# Why does my rake abort?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I get the following stack when I run `rake rails:update:bin`

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- google/api_client
/Users/jonathangrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
/Users/jonathangrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/jonathangrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
/Users/jonathangrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
/Users/jonathangrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
/Users/jonathangrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
/Users/jonathangrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
/Users/jonathangrant/omnivirt/adsoptimal-upload/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/jonathangrant/omnivirt/adsoptimal-upload/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/Users/jonathangrant/omnivirt/adsoptimal-upload/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/jonathangrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/Users/jonathangrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/jonathangrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:686:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/jonathangrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/jonathangrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/jonathangrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/jonathangrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `block in run'
/Users/jonathangrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/jonathangrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/rake-11.3.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/Users/jonathangrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/jonathangrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/jonathangrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/jonathangrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/jonathangrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Why am I getting this issue?

I am using Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.1.5 on my OSX 10.11.16 Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the surface answer is because Ruby can't find `google/api_client`. ;) But obviously that's not super helpful.

First, try putting in place a couple of best practices:

- Install [RVM](https://rvm.io),
- Create and use a gemset for your project (`rvm use 2.0.0@my-awesome-project --create`).
- Run `bundle install`.
- Then try the rake task again. What happens now?

(those best practices are RVM + gemsets)